# Angular show all reusable components with examples

Tags: angular

Is there any library that could help to collect all components that are meant to be reused accross project(s) in order to have some API-like page where one could find if the component that solves the problem already exists, see its usages and examples, see what it looks like and API?

I've seen UIJar but it requres tests and I want something easier to use.

Comment: Have a look to storybook

Comment: Storybook should be good for you

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it